# Geocoder Maps Api to string php

Tags: php, javascript

Intento sacar la dirección recibida por geolocalización y guardarla en mysql. Pero no recibo que puedo pasar el var a string. El mismo codigo lo pruebo con un var que no tiene que ver con google api y funciona correcto.

Gracias un saludo

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.92488028662047, 72.8232192993164);
        var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {

                    var Var_JavaScript = "Location: " + results[1].formatted_address;
 alert(Var_JavaScript);
                }
            }

        });

</script>
<?php
    $var_PHP = "<script> document.writeln(Var_JavaScript); </script>"; // igualar el valor de la variable JavaScript a PHP 
    echo $var_PHP   // muestra el resultado 
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que ocurre? ¿Hay algún error?

Comment: string no tiene ningun valor. es vacion .  echo $var_PHP  no da respuesta

Comment: No entiendo mucho por qué mezclas aquí código Javascript con PHP. ¿El `alert(Var_JavaScript);` tampoco muestra nada? ¿Podrías explicar mejor qué es lo que quieres hacer para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: me hace falta string para poder introducir la direccion en mysql. alert si funciona.

Comment: Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es pasar `Var_JavaScript` al servidor para hacer la inserción. Lo mejor para hacer eso es Ajax.

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO `fichaje` (`id`, `usuario`, `lat`, `long`, `status`, `fecha`, `hora`, `direccion`) VALUES (NULL, '$usuario', '$lat', '$long', '$status', '$date', '$date2', '$var_PHP);";

Comment: Si obtienes los datos desde el cliente (Javascript) y quieres usar esos datos en el servidor (PHP), tienes que pasar esos datos del cliente al servidor y lo mejor para eso Ajax. Lee sobre Ajax y cómo funciona, al principio puede ser un poco complicado entenderlo (en un día se aprende), pero cuando lo dominas descubres un nuevo mundo que simplifica las cosas de un modo admirable. O, si hay una API para PHP puedes también hacerlo todo desde el servidor.

Comment: Gracias. Voi a mirar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas mezclando cosas que haces en el cliente con cosas que se hacen en el servidor.
Lo mejor en este caso es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.92488028662047, 72.8232192993164);
        var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {    

                    address = results[1].formatted_address;
                    //Aqui con ajax llama a un proc. php que actulice la base de datos
                       $.ajax({
                            url: "upd_base.php", 
                            data : { address : address },
                            type : 'POST',
                            success: function(result){
                                alert('valor actualizado');
                       }});
                }
            }

        });

</script>
```

Para la llamada a ajax utiliza jquery.
Espero te sirva!!

Comment: esto ya lo e probado, gracias. Pero como viene la informacion por api , desde un dispozitivo mobil o desde otra pagina php (mismo web) . Tanto si viene por api de parte de android como desde web que manda por ajax los datos para no recargar la web , este subpagina no quere hacer otro ajax y se queda aqui .